# import CSS and JS from the same GAS project into Spreadsheet HtmlOutput

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, include, google-sheets

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices) tutorial, I'm trying to import into a GAS Html file a CSS and a JS file, both within the same project. The tutorial works fine as a **web app**, what I want to do now is to show an HtmlOutput on the associated spreadsheet, with the same content.

I tried to create the HtmlOutput on the Spreadsheet as follows:

```
function test(request){
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page');
    ss.show(html);
}
```

and I'm getting this result (as you can see the **getContent** and the **include** are not working as expected):

[image]

These are the html, css and gs documents:

**Code.gs**

```
//--- this function is called onclick on a Spreadsheet custom menu
function test(request){
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page');
    ss.show(html);
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

**Page.html**

```
<?!= getContent("Stylesheet.html"); ?>

<div>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p> test </p>
</div>

<?! include('Javascript'); ?>
```

**Stylesheet.html**

```
<style>
p{ 
    color: green;
} 
</style>
<div>

</div>
```

**Javascript.html**

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    alert("loaded!");
});
</script>
<div>

</div>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance, best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tutorial you tried you were using

```
HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate();
```

You have to use the same approach in the context of a spreadsheet Ui.

so, instead of

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page');
    ss.show(html);
```

use

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate();
    ss.show(html);
```

and it  works if you change also your html file like below (use "include" to include the style sheet):

```
<?!= include("Stylesheet.html"); ?>

<div>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p> test </p>
</div>

<?! include('Javascript'); ?>
```